# How to fetch values from a one2many field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

In customer invoice in the account module there is a one2many field,

```
invoice_line = fields.One2many('account.invoice.line', 'invoice_id', string='Invoice Lines')
```

Using this field we can add multiple products in the invoice. After adding multiple products how to segregate those products from this field, so that i will get product ids.

Suppose if we save two products, we will have two entries. From these two entry i need to separate each product's product id

Comment: from what do you want to get these product ids?

Comment: Using this field we will save products. From this product i want product id

Comment: I don't understand, how do you want to use it. But this field builds relationship to `account.invoice.line`. There is a relationship to `product.product` in `account.invoice.line`. So you need to get the object `account.invoice.line` with this `invoice_id` and fetch his data. There is a field `product_id` in this data

Comment: @julivico. I am sorry that yoy didn't understand my qiestion. Suppose if we save two products, we will have two entries. From these two entry i need to separate each product id

Comment: *Using this field we can add multiple products in the invoice*. **It's false.** You can add multiple invoice lines in the invoice. And the invoice_line includes product_id. Where do you want to get product_ids? In the same module or other module?

Comment: @julivico. At same module account.invoice

Comment: ok, did you inherit the module or modify the module directly?

Comment: I just inherited the account.invoice model

Comment: odoo is very complex. It's difficult to help u, if i don't understand, what you want to do. Can you please post some code, what you tried or more description? otherwise i can post a general solution. But it will may be not work for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your question i can only give you a general answer. I hope, you can start with it.

In a odoo model (`osv.osv`, ...) you can use `self.pool.get("model name")` to get the object pool for any model. With this pool you can use the method `read()` to read the data.
A Odoo model is stored mostly in one table on the database.

Firstly you need to understand the relationship of the objects in Odoo. In your case it's so:

```
account.invoice --(invoice_line_ids:one2many)--> account.invoice.line --(product:many2one)-> product
```

- Reading of **one2many** field returns a `list` of IDs of the destination objects.
- Reading of **Many2one** field returns an `int` value of ID of the destination object.

Here is an example to get product ids from the lines of a invoice:

```
# call object pool for account.invoice
invoice_pool = self.pool.get("account.invoice")

# here you need the invoice_id to get the data. 
# you can get it by parsing the parameter context
found_invoices = invoice_pool.read(cr, uid, [invoice_id,], ["invoice_line_ids"], context)

# It returns a list, but i gave only one invoice_id.
# the list has maximun one element. we need the frist element
found_invoice = found_invoices[0] if found_invoices else None

invoice_line_ids = found_invoice["invoice_line_ids"]

# the same with "account.invoice.line"
invoice_line_pool = self.pool.get("account.invoice.line")
invoice_lines = invoice_line_pool.read(cr, uid, invoice_line_ids, ["product_id"], context)

# Here you have the product ids
# I don't need to get the first element, because it returns a int
product_ids = [line["product_id"] for line in invoice_lines]
```

`cr`, `uid`, `context` are parameters, which you get from a request. You can get it by overwriting the method `read`,  `write`, ....
Important: you need the `invoice_id` to start. You can get this value by parsing the variable `context`.

You can use `logging` to show the content of `context` in log file:

```
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_logger.info("context type: " + type(context))
_logger.info("context content: " + str(context))
```

*P/S: You will need to customize my code to fit with yours, because i don't know many about your idea. I'm working with Odoo 9. But it's mostly the same core with Odoo 8*